# Twilio - Gather - Wait the end of the message before sending the NumDigits to the API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Here is what my API answers to Twilio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather action="/api/v1/twilio/OnPIN" numDigits="5">
        <Say voice="alice" language="fr-CA">BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA in french</Say>
        <Say>BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA  in english</Say>
    </Gather>
    <Redirect method="GET">/api/v1/twilio/OnFail</Redirect>
</Response>
```

When I call the Twilio I use the correct phone number + the extension.
The message starts to play, then it cuts and I m redirected to the next action.
If I cal the correct phone number without the extension, I can hear the complete message.

From What I can read on the Twilio documentation:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#numdigits

> Once the caller enters the final digit of 94117, Twilio will
>   immediately submit the data to your action URL.

I tried with this answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather action="/api/v1/twilio/OnPIN" speechTimeout="auto">
        <Say voice="alice" language="fr-CA">BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA in french</Say>
        <Say>BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA  in english</Say>
    </Gather>
    <Redirect method="GET">/api/v1/twilio/OnFail</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Like before, the message was cut, and then I waited few seconds with silence before next instructions, I guess it s because the Timeout by default is 5 sec.

**Question**: How can I configure Twilio to wait the end of the message before sending the numdigits to the API?

Thanks
Cedric

Comment: Could you place the <say> verb outside of and before the gather?  This would let Twilio complete the entire say before starting the gather.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, I already thought about this idea, but in this case, the digit will be already sent and will be missed. I think the only way is to increase the time between the start of the call and the digit sending by adding more pause. Like +1 xxx xxx xxxx ,,,, [digits].

Comment: when using numDigits there isn't a way to subsequently tell Twilio to wait for the <say> to be completed.  As the docs say, one the final digit is detected we move to the next set of TwiML instructions as provided by the URL configured in the action parameter.  I guess I'm also not 100% clear on what you're trying to accomplish.